# How to use sticky sessions with TCP ports in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, sticky-sessions

I have an application that runs across multiple AWS instances, and I need to have them load balanced with sticky sessions. AWS load balancing works fine for HTTP, but AWS doesn't give you the option of doing it for TCP, which is a problem for me as I'm using websockets that go over TCP that need to be load balanced & sticky-sessioned as well.

How do I go about doing this? Or, if I can't, what's a workable alternative? My end goal is to have multiple copies of this application, living on separate servers, but with users being able to access them all through a single link without them even realizing. I'm not too fussed how I achieve this.

Comment: One alternative would be sharing state of the application between all instances, then one doesn't need sticky sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Amazon's Application Load Balancers (ALBs) send websockets through HTTP listeners, so my switching from ELB to ALB I was able to achieve this functionality I wanted without the need to sticky-session TCP.